# Finding one of the roots of an equation

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I am trying to one of the roots of the following equation $$z^5 = -16 + (16\sqrt 3)i$$ which is $$z = 2e^{\frac{(6k+2)\pi}{15}i}$$
However, I have trouble getting that root. Here is what I have done:
$$|z^5| = \sqrt {(-16)^2 + (16\sqrt3)^2}$$
$$|z| = \sqrt[5] {32} = 2$$ Since the coordinate lies in the 2nd quadrant, $$arg(z) = \pi - tan^{-1} (\frac{16\sqrt3}{16}) = \frac{2\pi}{3}$$
Therefore, $$\begin{align} z & = re^{i\theta}\\
& = 2e^{(\frac{2k\pi}{5}+\frac{2\pi}{3})i}\\
& = 2e^{\frac{(6k+10)\pi}{15}i}\\
\end{align}$$
Please explain to me where have I gone wrong.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470644/finding-the-roots-of-unity  and see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Roots_of_complex_numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the two last lines you forgot divide $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$ by $5$. You wrote
\begin{align} z & = re^{i\theta}\\
& = 2e^{(\frac{2k\pi}{5}+\color{red}{\frac{2\pi}{3}})i}\\
& = 2e^{\frac{(6k+10)\pi}{15}i}\\
\end{align}

When you must do
\begin{align} z & = re^{i\theta}\\
& = 2e^{(\frac{2k\pi}{5}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{2\pi}{3}})i}\\
& = \boxed{\color{blue}{2e^{\frac{(6k+2)\pi}{15}i}}}\\
\end{align}